# simple validation form with javascript

Tags: javascript, validation

i have a 'div' tag included error message on the my form.
this tag displaying when button is clicked and inputs are null.
my code is working but, 'div' tag is hide speedly.

```html
<htlm>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="ShowError">
<h3>Username Or Password is incorrect.</h3>
</div>
<form id="Main" method="POST">
<input id="User" type="text" name="Name" placeholder="Enter Your Username">
<br>
<input id="Pass" type="password" name="Pass" placeholder="Enter Your Password"/>
<br>
<button id="bt">Login</button>
<button >Cancel</button>
</form>
</body>
<script src=""></script>
</html>
```

```css
div#ShowError{
opacity:0.0;
}
```

```
var btn = document.getElementById("bt");
btn.addEventListener("click",func);

var Username = document.getElementById("User");
var Password = document.getElementById("Pass");

function func()
{

    if(Username.value == "" || Password.value == "")
    {
        document.getElementById("ShowError").style.opacity = "1.0";
    }
}
```

Comment: [The HTML5 placeholder attribute is not a substitute for the label element](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201204/the_html5_placeholder_attribute_is_not_a_substitute_for_the_label_element/)

Comment: `var Username` — Variable names starting with a capital letter are traditionally reserved for Constructor Functions in JavaScript. Don't use them for other kinds of value.

Comment: You should run your HTML through [a validator](https://validator.nu/).

Comment: `btn.addEventListener("click",func);` — In general, it is better to use the submit event of the form over a click event of a submit button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to slowdown the opacity change of validation error message. For example, slowly change opacity 0.0 to 1.0, right? If so, for slow change of opacity of the validation error message you have to add the [css transition](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_transition.asp) property using javascript to your validation error message div.

```
function func(event)
{

    if(Username.value == "" || Password.value == "")
    {

        document.getElementById("ShowError").style.transition = "all 2s"
        document.getElementById("ShowError").style.opacity = 1;
    }
}
```

and also to stop reloading the page when you click login button you can include type="button" in your login button

```
<button type="button" id="bt">Login</button>
```

**Working demo :**

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("bt");
btn.addEventListener("click",func);
//document.getElementById("ShowError").style.transition = "all 2s"
var Username = document.getElementById("User");
var Password = document.getElementById("Pass");

Username.addEventListener("input",func2)
Password.addEventListener("input",func2)

function func(event)
{

    if(Username.value == "" || Password.value == "")
    {

        document.getElementById("ShowError").style.transition = "all 2s"
        document.getElementById("ShowError").style.opacity = 1;
    }
}

function func2(){
  if(Username.value !== "" && Password.value !== ""){
            document.getElementById("ShowError").style.transition = "all 2s"
        document.getElementById("ShowError").style.opacity = 0;
  }
}
```

```css
div#ShowError{
opacity:0.0;
}
```

```html
<div id="ShowError">
<h3>Username Or Password is incorrect.</h3>
</div>
<form id="Main" method="POST">
<input id="User" type="text" name="Name" placeholder="Enter Your Username">
<br>
<input id="Pass" type="password" name="Pass" placeholder="Enter Your Password"/>
<br>
<button type="button" id="bt">Login</button>
<button >Cancel</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you...but if inputs are filled error message not hiding on the form

Comment: @hamid You need to track if there is any change in the input value to achieve this functionality. Add eventListener to both of your input field. Check the updated answer

Answer (score 5):

Clicking a submit button will submit the form.

So the JavaScript runs, the form submits, and a new page is loaded. The JavaScript hasn't run on the new page.

[Prevent the default behaviour](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) of the event if you don't want the form to submit.

```
function func(e)
{

    if(Username.value == "" || Password.value == "")
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        document.getElementById("ShowError").style.opacity = "1.0";
    }
}
```

Comment: Classics never die :-)